# Create A Method To Iterate Through Objects Properties

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any way to wrtie code to do this:

Foreach property in MyObject;
check to see if property has a DataMember Validator on is with IsRequired=true;

```
[DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired=true)]
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

[DataMember(Order = 3)]
public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
```

If so check if the object has a notNull or empty value in it;

So in summary I create a method called CheckForRequiredFields(object o)

pass it an "Address" object in this case with properties listed above. The code Sees the first property has RequiredField=true so it checks that the Address object passed to it has a value for AddressLine1

Comment: Did you know .NET already has a set of classes that provide this functionality in the DataAnnotations namespace? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like (from memory so no guarantees of correctness):

```
foreach(var propInfo in o.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var dmAttr = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as DataMemberAttribute;
    if (dmAttr == null)
        continue;

    object propValue = propInfo.GetValue(o, null);
    if (dmAttr.IsRequired && propValue == null)
        // It is required but does not have a value... do something about it here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Take a look at [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) . You can take your type, call `Type.GetProperties()` on it and retrieve `PropertyInfo` for each property.

From the `PropertyInfo` you can get its attributes (using the `GetCustomAttributes` method), and look for the `DataMember` attribute. If you find one, check for its `IsRequired`.

Comment: The `Attributes` property will not tell them if the property is decorated with custom attributes (that is what `GetCustomAttributes` is for).